# Finding all references on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been using the Eclipse references (Ctrl+shift+G) for sometime now. I notice that Eclipse misses finding some references sometimes. Is there something I must configure to get this working correctly?

Comment: I've never had any problems with this that I've noticed. Per default should Ctrl+shift+g search in the whole workspace.

Comment: Can you give an example of something that it's missed? I have not had a problem either.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? Personally I have never experienced what you describe. Also, make sure your Workspace is synced with the filesystem before doing a reference check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem may be related to issues concerning Eclipse's CODAN indexer. Try to rebuild the index by clicking `[Project Explorer] > Index > Rebuild`. Goto `Eclipse > Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer` and check if your indexer is setup correctly...

Comment: Hi Eric, could you explain where that should be? I tried to find it in Eclipse, but I could not find the "Index" reference. That said, I'm running 4.1. Maybe it is only available on some platforms, or only if auto rebuilds have been disabled?

Comment: I had the same difficulty as Maarten and found the Rebuild option within the `Project menu>C/C++ Index > Rebuild`

Answer (score 4):

I just sorted out a similar-sounding problem.

In my case I was mistakenly ending up with a project->JAR dependency rather than a project->project dependency.

This involved a specialized import of a set of Java-based projects, with logic to 
set up a project->project dependency if possible and a project->JAR dependency if
the source was unavailable.

(This wasn't using Maven but from what I know of Maven<->Eclipse integration I could
imagine this happening in a similar case).

So typically I get a project->project dependency but I had messed something up in my filesystem so I ended up with a project->JAR dependency without realizing it...and Ctrl+Shift+G stopped working.

Comment: How did you solve this? I do have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Christian, it was with an internal plugin so the solution doesn't really generalize.   But maybe it would help to suggest you start by looking at your **.classpath** file and see if you see what you'd expect.   E.g. where you want **kind="src"** maybe you're ending up with something else.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me working with a Java/Maven project just recently as well. The version of Eclipse was Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

Rebuilding the projects using `Project -> Clean...` did not help. The solution was to **close** and then **reopen** the projects. After that, the call hierarchy was correctly calculated again.

Answer (score 2):

There's a long standing open bug for this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108749

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well, and a comment in the above mentioned bug report resolved it for me:
Exit the workbench and delete the Java search index:
- go into <workspaceDir>\plugins\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core
- delete 'savedIndexNames.txt'
- delete all *.index
Restart

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have imported two maven projects to eclipse. One was depending on another and references in dependent project were not found. I have right clicked on dependent project choose preferences->java build path then removed dependency from Libraries tab and added same dependency to projects path. Of course I had to have both projects in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your project is of the type expected. My similar symptom turned out to be because the eclipse project had been recently re-imported as a general project. Once I realized that and converted it to a C/C++ project, find references again worked as expected.